# meteor method assign return to template handlebar

Tags: javascript, meteor

This is the method inside Meteor.startup function

```
return Meteor.methods({
  whatsUp: function() {
   return "Up";
  }
});
```

And here is the event code triggering the method

```
Template.whats_up.events({
  'click .checkwhatsup': function() {
    Meteor.call('whatsUp');
  }
});
```

And here is a code simply doing returning a variable straight to the DOM

```
Template.whats_up.up = function() {
  var whats = "Up";
  return whats;
};
```

My question is how can I do the same function as on the last js code,

but only after I click on a button.

Here is the html template + handlebars

```
<template name="whats_up">
  <button class="checkwhatsup">What is Up?!</button>
  {{up}}
</template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking to do something like this:

```
Template.whats_up.events({
  'click .checkwhatsup': function() {
    Meteor.call('whatsUp', function(res) {
      Session.set('whats', res);
    });
  }
});

Template.whats_up.up = function() {
  return Session.get('whats');
};
```

The idea is to use a reactive data source (in this case, `Session`) to handle this. You could also update a `Collection` in your method and use a collection cursor in your helper function. That way there's no callback function for the method call (and the template can update when other users call the method). Depends on your actual usage case.

Comment: question: how do I display the variable returned if its an array,
atm it returns [object Object].

Comment: Usually you would use an `{{#each yourArray}}` in handlebars. Otherwise you can specify a custom `.toString()` method on the variable.

Comment: Although are you sure it's actually an array and not an object? `[1,2,3].toString()` returns `"1,2,3"`, not `"[object Object]"`.

Comment: I think its a 2d array of sorts, its the one you get from Collections.. :S

Comment: I'm guessing you mean a cursor, then use `{{#each yourHelperName}}`. Meteor's `{{#each}}` understands how to iterate over cursors returned by helpers.

Comment: So can I use the session.get to make it a cursor and then return it for the handlebars to iterate through?

Comment: Hmm no don't do that. If you're using collections, you don't need `Session` because collections are already reactive! `Template.myTemplate.myHelper = function() { return myCollection.find(); };`

Comment: problem is im using if statements to make sure I don't get the information I don't want, I can make it work if I don't press a button to do it first, but I'd like to press a button then do the calculations and show me the information.

Comment: not sure if I should just slam that variable inside another collection and then use .find() on that one :S but then i'd have to remove everything from it first everytime I want to use it.

Comment: Ah I see what you mean. Yes in that case, you might be able to store the cursor in `Session`. I've never tried that before. I would probably store the Mongo selector object in `Session` and return the cursor w/ the `Session` selector from your helper. I wouldn't store cursors in `Session` because it seems simpler to just store dumb objects and primitive types in there. I don't know how a cursor object would react to a reload (`Session` vars are preserved on reload).

Comment: My brain just froze :D
I'm thinking I might do the Session.set('cursor', res);
change that into a variable using "var x = Session.get('cursor');
then Meteor.call('removeAllfromCollection'); (remove everything from collection function)
then insert the variable into the collection

and then just find the collection in the 
Template.whats.var = function() {

But no idea if that will work, to call a function inside a call to another function.

Comment: Yikes, I think you're making this too complicated. Take a look at the leaderboard example. On the click event, a player id is stored in the session. One of the helpers uses that session var to create a cursor from the collection. That's all.

Comment: What exactly are you doing in your server method? If it's just working with a collection, you can just do that on the client with the client mongo API. You can't return a cursor from a method AFAIK, and you wouldn't want to even if you could.

Comment: Will do, thank you for helping me through this :)
I had a feeling I was making this way too complicated.